# Inequality relying on integer partitions and dominance ordering

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions

Let $\lambda$, $\mu$ be two partitions of a natural number $n$, such that $\lambda$ dominates $\mu$ in the usual dominance order on partitions.

I would like to prove that if $q\geq 2$ is a natural number, then
$$\sum_{j\in \mu} q^j \leq  \sum_{i\in \lambda} q^i $$

I'm sure this must be well-known if it is true, but I cannot find it in the literature. Even a reference for this (or indeed a counterexample!) would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) since $x \mapsto q^x$ is convex for $q \geq 1$. (Credit where credit is due: I essentially learned this from Fedor Petrov.)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!